# Wrong company name is seen in TestFlight emails

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight, iphone-developer-program

I have checked my company's developer account and checked organization name over there. I have found the company name is proper, that is "MY COMAPANY NAME **Inc.**" but while me and my clients get TestFlight invitations, they see company name with "MY COMAPANY NAME **Pvt. Ltd.**" as following:

[image]

Comment: I faced the same issue, you found any solution @NSPratik

Comment: Better you consult Apple.. Only they can do it.

Comment: Our company member consulted Apple and after their conversation and document submission (if needed) with Apple, company name has been updated..

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @NSPratik

Comment: @NSPratik : I am having the same issue. I have send a message to Apple but haven't heard any update on it. Can you provide the email/contact or the link to Contact Apple?